# If Condition Issues

Tags: python, while-loop

I have made a simple game for python in a function called (**game()**). I made an **IF** condition within a **While** loop that asks a person if he wants to play the game again (yes=execute game(), no=break) but im facing an issue if the user didnt put neither yes nor no. how do I make it repeat the IF block until the user either put either yes or no. The code is shown as below. Thanks

`

```
while True:
     game()
     user=input("Do you want to play again? \n")
     if user=="yes":
        game()
     elif user=="no":
         print("Game is over")
         break
     else:
        ("Please Enter Yes or no") `
```

Comment: That already is the case. The first call to `game` at the top of the loop should probably be before the loop though. If it's in the loop, it will be called whenever the loop starts; including when the user doesn't enter anything valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

```py
play = "yes"
while play == "yes":
    game()
    play = "unknown"
    while play not in ["yes", "no"]:
        play = input("Play again (yes/no)? ").lower().strip()
```

This does the following:

- Assumes initial ***play*** value of `yes` to play the game at least once.
- Ensure the user answers `yes` or `no` (ignoring case and leading or trailing white space).
- Continues the loop only for the `yes` case.

There's improvements you can make if, for example, you want a different message when user enters an invalid response, but that code should be a good start.

---

If you *do* decide it needs more features, that's probably when you could argue it would be better in a helper function, something like:

```py
def ask(prompt, allowed):
    resp = input(prompt).lower().strip()
    while resp not in allowed:
        print(f"*** Not one of [{", ".join(allowed)}]")
        resp = input(prompt).lower().strip()
    return resp

game()
while ask("Play again (yes/no)? ", ["yes", "no"]) == "yes":
    game()
```

Putting it into a helper function means that you can add all sorts of wonderful features as needs require, probably with default-value parameters so the most common case doesn't require them, just by changing that one function.

For example, you may want to allow for a different subsequent prompt and making it case sensitive or not:

```py
def _ask_case(value, ignore_case):
    return value.lower() if ignore case else value

def ask(prompt, allowed, prompt2=None, ignore_case=True):
    if prompt2 is None:
        prompt2 = prompt
    if ignore_case:
        allowed = [item.lower() for item in allowed]
    str_allow = f"*** Not one of [{', '.join(allowed)}]"

    resp = _ask_case(input(prompt).strip(), ignore_case)
    while resp not in allowed:
        print(str_allow)
        resp = _ask_case(input(prompt2).strip(), ignore_case)

    return resp
```

I haven't tested that code (so it may not work) and it may not be immediately necessary for your purposes, but the idea is just to show that refactoring it into a helper function means you can use it everywhere, and very simply, but still have a lot of power if or when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

Since `game()` is at the start of your loop, each iteration of the loop will start with that (i.e. playing the game again), regardless of what the user entered on the previous iteration -- the only way to prevent that is to `break` the loop (which happens in the "no" condition, but not in the `else` that corresponds to invalid input).

To fix that, just move that line outside of the loop:

```
game()  # first game happens automatically, before the input loop starts
while True:
     user=input("Do you want to play again? \n")
     if user=="yes":
        game()  # subsequent games ONLY happen if the user says yes
     elif user=="no":
         print("Game is over")
         break
     else:
        ("Please Enter Yes or no")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems I see with your code

- First is the user input needs to be in its own loop
- You are calling the game twice if the user says yes (once after the if condition returns true and once more after the loop repeats)

You want to set a flag to check that the user input is valid. Also, you don't want to call game() within the check.

```
while True:
   game()

   user="maybe"
   while user!="no" and user!="yes":
      user=input("Do you want to play again? \n")
     
   if user=="no":
      print("Game is over")
      break
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to make your code better, try this:

```
game()
while True:
     user=input("Do you want to play again? Please Enter yes or no\n").lower().strip()
     if user=="yes":
         game()
     elif user=="no":
         print("Game is over")
         break
     else:
         print("Please Enter yes or no")
```

- Game must be started before the while loop
- User Input must be case-insensitive
- else row needs print()